# Character "1" with long serif

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm looking for a character "1" with looong horizontal serif at the bottom (in math mode).
Currently I use `\mathtt{1}`, but would prefer longer. I also tried stretching it horizontally by `\scalebox`, but then it produced some Fatal error, something like "too complex task", probably because of the subscripts.

Does anyone know a font or easy way to create "1" with long serif?

Comment: I think you could improve your question by including a MWE illustrating your failed attempt with \scalebox (probably not necessary, but I think it would be nice!)

Comment: sorry, what MWE stands for?

Comment: I am really sorry. Your reputation was high enough that I though you would have come across this before. MWE stands for "minimal working example" and it means a compilable code starting from `\begin{document}` and ending in `\end{document}`, including all packages you may need. Of course, your code wouldn't be compilable per se since it would have an error! For more on MWE see [this meta answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/14).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can probably fake it by overlaying a suitable rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\protected\def\one{\mathpalette\xone{}}
\def\xone#1#2{\ooalign{%
\hss$#1\mkern3mu1\mkern3mu$\hss\cr
$#1\mkern1mu\hrulefill\mkern1mu$}}

\begin{document}

\[1+2+3+1\one1  X^{1+2+3+\one }\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Maybe it's a bit longer. What are there 'mkern' and '3mu's? I guess I should set these like 2.6mu instead of 3mu, right?

Comment: yes mu are math units 1/16 of an em usually, they get smaller in superscripts so good to use for this sort if thing there is a total width of 3 either side of the 1 and then 1mu of white space either side of the hrule so the rule doesn't touch adjacent characters, but play with the numbers as you wish.